# Mathematical notation for matrix slicing

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

Suppose I have a matrix $M$. From that matrix, I create a matrix $N$ by only keeping some rows of $M$. The rows to keep are given in a vector or set called $r$. Then I do the same with columns in vector/set $c$ in order to obtain matrix $Q$.

In a notation similar to Matlab or Numpy, this is realized by slicing:

```
N = M[r, :] # keep only rows whose index is in r
Q = N[:, c] # keep only columns whose index is in c
```

**How does the mathematical notation for such a construct look?** I'm also happy with a solution that does the slicing in one step.

Comment: There is no problem with using any notation that you want as long as you define it. That notation is quite succinct, and it is also consistent with notation broadly used in math. After all, a matrix is a function from the indexes to the values of the entries. Just like the notation $f(A)$ is used for the values of $f$ on a subset of its domain, it would be quite natural to do the same for a matrix. Even $M_{\cdot,C}$ if you need even more space. Just define the notation clearly before using it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would write $N =(M_{i j})_{\substack{i \in r\\ 1 \le j \le m}}$ and $Q=(M_{i j})_{\substack{1 \le i \le n\\ j \in c}}$.